# opencvdotnet and FFMPEG - are there any integration options?

Tags: c#, .net, opencv, video, ffmpeg

opencvdotnet or its analogs and FFMPEG - are there any integration options? like open FLV flie or save to some exotic format... Please, provide a simple code example.

Comment: I'm not aware of any, but would love to see one. BTW, I recommend using Emgu CV over opencvdotnet (more featurism and portability)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about OpenCVDotNet.. but as far as I remember OpenCV (the old C/C++ lib) used to have some sosrt of integration with FFMPEG

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/FFMPEG

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be the first to create this and grab the market. FFMPEG is great tool to play with.